# How to display loop data on a textfield

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, textfield

I am currently trying to display data from an array in a textfield, but only one item from the array will show up.  This is what I have so far:

```
while (j<count){

    if (b != "no") {                 
        tfBIDI.setText(book[j]);
    } else { 
        tfBIDO.setText(book[j]);
    }
    j++;
}
```

Is is possible to display all of the data from an array in a textfield?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `b` is a String, you cannot compare Strings with the "==" (or !=) operator. Use `.equals()`. Also, you will need to append to the text area, and not call `.setText()`.

Comment: Construct a `String` with your desired message, then set the text of the textfield. Or use `tfBIDO.setText(Arrays.toString(book));`

Comment: Using the append worked well.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> try this out...

```
String str_yes = "";
String str_no ="";
while (j<count){

  if (b.equals("no")) {  
      no += book[j];                     
   } else { 
   str_yes += book[j];
}
    j++;
   }

tfBIDI.setText(str_no);
tfBIDO.setText(str_yes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the text data of the book array, and set that `String` as the text of the `TextField` only once. Right now each iteration of your while loop updates the `TextFields` text, so you see only the value of the last update

```
 String[] data = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
            sb.append(data[idx]);
            sb.append(", ");
        }

        String joinedData = sb.toString();
        //or 
        joinedData = Stream.of(data).collect(joining(","));

        textField.setText(joinedData);
```

Comment: Or [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)...